# Why doesn't nmap ping scan need root permission

Tags: linux, permissions, nmap

As I know, ping is a tool that requires root permission (set-uid) or CAP_NET_RAW Capability.

But I found that, when I start a Nmap ping scan(-sn), no privilege permission required:

```
# getcap /usr/bin/nmap
# ls -al /usr/bin/nmap 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2445920 May 28  2016 /usr/bin/nmap
# su -s /bin/bash www-data
$ id
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
$ nmap -sn example.com

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-02-17 16:35 CST
Nmap scan report for example.com (93.184.216.34)
Host is up (0.011s latency).
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 11.05 seconds
```

So how does ping scan of Nmap work? Why does ping need root permission and the nmap doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

> When you run an Nmap ping scan as root, the default is to use the ICMP and ACK methods. Non-root users will use the connect() method, which attempts to connect to a machine, waiting for a response, and tearing down the connection as soon as it has been established (similar to the SYN/ACK method for root users, but this one establishes a full TCP connection!)

From the [nmap website](https://nmap.org/bennieston-tutorial/).